# Skip a task in Github action based on the value of a variable defined in another task

Tags: github-actions

In a Github action, I've a task that performs some checks and outputs a Boolean flag as a result. I would like to skip other tasks if the flag is False. I'm not sure about the syntax, the following does not work as expected.

```yaml
name: test
jobs:
  test_job:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
      steps:
        - name: Create flag
          id: create_flag
          run: |
            # run some checks and put results in FLAG
            # and make that available to other tasks.
            # "true" for true, and "false" for false (so string instead of boolean).
            echo "::set-output name=FLAG::$FLAG"

        - name: Run-me if FLAG is true
          if: ${{ steps.create_flag.outputs.FLAG }} == "true"
          run: |
           # some logic to run if flag==true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep 'true' in single quotes.

Check GitHub expressions section related to conversions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions)

```
if: ${{ steps.create_flag.outputs.FLAG == 'true' }}
if: steps.create_flag.outputs.FLAG == 'true'
```

Here is an example run of your workflow:

https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/runs/5558400970?check_suite_focus=true

And source of the workflow:

https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/actions/runs/1988349309/workflow

Comment: Using either of those causes github not triggering the execution of the action, so I guess it does not like the syntax.

Comment: Specifically, it says "unexpected symbol: "true""

Comment: I can get pass this using `True` instead of `"true"`. However, I mention Boolean type in the question for simplicity, while in my application I've `string` type and make assertions based on the value of string. Hence, I cannot simply replace the assertion with `if: steps.create_flag.outputs.FLAG`.